# Configuration issues trying to install Ruby on Mac

Tags: ruby, xcode, compiler-construction, configure

When I run `rvm install ruby-1.9.3`, I get this error message when configuring

`Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/robbor911/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/robbor911/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/robbor911/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.`

All posts on this issue so far tell users to download XCode and install it, but I have it installed-- it even runs successfully.

From what I've gather, my problem has something to do with the terminal unable to locate the compiler's necessary for the download.

I even managed to locate the compilers at `Xcode/Contents/Developer/usr/bin` and `Xode/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin`

Does anyone know why, when I installed XCode, my compilers weren't set up properly or how I can manually correct this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 4.3 no longer installs the command-line tools by default. You can install them from the Downloads pane in Xcode's preferences.

Comment: This worked! I also had to use this command to get it to run : `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang`

Answer (score 1):

I just ran across this issue the other day. The way I was able to get it running:

1) I downloaded and installed [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) package from Github.

2) ran `rvm get head && rvm reload && rvm reinstall 1.9.3`

Worked for me. Running OS Lion 10.7